# Web Access to Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware, virtualization, vmware-server

Is their a way to access a web server such as windows server 2003 installed on a virtual box such as vmware from the host machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If VMware is set to use bridged networking, then each guest OS effectively has its own IP address, like brien said, you just point your browser to that address.

Comment: perfect, i didn't want it to take over my localhost address if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you configure your virtual machine to use bridged networking, instead of NAT, it will have its own IP address "beside" the host machine, instead of a local IP address "behind" it. Then you can connect to the virtual machine, using that IP number.

(Disclaimer: I've used VMware workstation for several years, but not their server products.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should just be able to point to the IP address of the VM.

How is your VM networking configured?

Comment: it was set to NAT networking, but i'm going to change it to bridged and assign it an ip address now.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this all over the place, just make sure that the vm has an ip configured.

Answer (score 0):

i believe vmware (workstation?) also has built in a virtual network client (VNC) that you can connect to - enable it by going to the configuration properties of the vm, and in the last tab there is a checkbox for it.

Answer (score 0):

IP address should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. You have to set your networkconnection to "bridged mode" in your VM. Then you have to find out the IP of your Webserver.

Sometimes Webservers have a redirect to a specific URL. In this case you can edit your host-file in C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts and add your IP with the redirected URL like this:

```
192.168.0.37 some.url-you.need
```

Then your Host can go to the Webserver. Even participants of your Ethernet can access the Webserver.